# About passing Vec<u8> parameters in pallet

Tags: pallet, vec

### Problem

How can I get the correct `Vec<u8>` in the pallet when I use `Vec<u8>` as the parameter of the pallet?

### code

```rust
pub fn generate_proof_vkey(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            proof_a: Vec<u8>,
            proof_b: Vec<u8>,
            proof_c: Vec<u8>,
            vk_alpha1: Vec<u8>,
            vk_beta_2: Vec<u8>,
            vk_gamma_2: Vec<u8>,
            vk_delta_2: Vec<u8>,
            vk_ic: Vec<Vec<u8>>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            let proof = ProofStr { pi_a: proof_a, pi_b: proof_b, pi_c: proof_c };
            log::info!("{:?}", proof.pi_a);
            let vkey = VkeyStr {
                alpha_1: vk_alpha1, 
                beta_2: vk_beta_2,
                gamma_2: vk_gamma_2,
                delta_2: vk_delta_2,
                ic: vk_ic,
            };
            <Pof<T>>::insert(who.clone(), &proof);
            <Vkey<T>>::insert(who.clone(),&vkey);
            Self::deposit_event(Event::<T>::ProofStored(proof, who.clone()));
            Self::deposit_event(Event::<T>::VerificationKeyStore(vkey, who));
            Ok(())
        }
```

I can get the correct `Vec<u8>` in the front end, but not in the pallet.

**In Polkadot js**:
[image]

**In the pallet——Maci-verifier**
[image]

In the pallet, when i print the `proof.pi_a`, it output the encoded data. However i want to get the vec data like in polkadot js instead of encoded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved this problem when i pass the decimal format of the vec instead of passing the vec directly. Because the vec is used to pass string, so when i pass the vec directly, it will be judged as the string, so it will be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

PolkadotJs did the `decode` for you.

In Rust, you need to do:

```rs
let proof = ProofStr::decode(&mut &*the_vec_output).unwrap();
```

Comment: thanks, but i pass the vec data which is the field of ProofStr struct. i tried to decode the vec, but failed

Comment: I didn't get what you want to do. You are trying to decode a `Vec<u8>` to a `Vec<u32>`.

But for the question. I think you want to decode the `ProofStr` from `Vec<u8>`.

Comment: But from your polkadotapps screenshot, it is a `ProofStr` that  decoded from a `Vec<u8>`.

Comment: `However i want to get the vec data like in polkadot js instead of encoded.`

This is what you said in the question. You want the polkadotapps's output. Actually it's a decoded `ProofStr`.

Comment: Also, `Vec<u8>` is aka bytes in computers. `Vec<u32>` is just a series of `u32`. I don't why you want this type.